# Получить количество блокировок в очереди. Nito.AsyncEx. C#

Tags: c#, async-await

В своей программе использую библиотеку Nito.AsyncEx (https://github.com/StephenCleary/AsyncEx). В своем коде использую класс AsyncLock для синхронизации действий. Возникла надобность узнать сколько на данный момент активных блокировок, но этот класс не имеет такого свойства.

В своей программе я создаю несколько экземпляров класса Worker и заношу их в коллекцию. Далее, программе подается команда выполнить определенное действие Worker-ом, с наименьшим количеством блокировок в очереди. Пример кода Worker-а:

```
public class Worker
{
    public int Id { get; private set; }
    public int someProperty1 { get; private set; }
    public int someProperty2 { get; private set; }

    AsyncLock _lock = new AsyncLock();

    public async Task ActionFirst()
    {
        using(await _lock.LockAsync())
        {
            // code
        }
    }

    public async Task ActionSecond()
    {
        using(await _lock.LockAsync())
        {
            // code
        }
    }

    public void ParallelActionFirst()
    {
        //code
    }

    public void ParallelActionSecond()
    {
        //code
    }
}
```

Воркеры могут выполнять довольно много функций (10+) параллельно, но некоторые из них должны выполняться последовательно (ActionFirst, ActionSecond).
Какой-либо их этих наборов действий должнен выполняться последовательно:

`ActionFirst -> ActionSecond
ActionFirst -> ActionFirst
ActionSecond -> ActionFirst
ActionSecond -> ActionSecond`

У воркеров есть ID и несколько других свойств. Некоторые задания предусматривают выбор конкретного воркера, но в случае, когда НЕ нужен определенный воркер (или подойдет для выполнения задания, бОльшая часть воркеров) и необходимо выполнить действие ActionFirst или ActionSecond, должен выбираться минимально загруженный.

Есть ли решения данной задачи, используя эту библиотеку или стандартные средства "из коробки" C#?

Answer (score 1):

*У меня есть такое ощущение, что ваша настоящая задача называется Producer-Consumer Problem*

Насколько я понял, ожидающие блокировки в воркерах у вас образуют нечто вроде входящей очереди - а подсчитывать их вам надо для балансировки.

Если это так, то правильным решением будет использование общей очереди свободных воркеров:

```
BufferBlock<Worker> workers = new BufferBlock<Worker>();

var worker = await workers.ReceiveAsync();
try 
{
  await worker.ActionFirst();
}
finally
{
  workers.Post(worker);
}
```

Здесь я использовал [`BufferBlock`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh160414(v=vs.110).aspx) из библиотеки [Tpl Dataflow](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/hh228603(v=vs.110).aspx) - но можно использовать и другие реализации асинхронных очередей. Например, `AsyncCollection` из пакета [AsyncCollections](https://www.nuget.org/packages/AsyncCollections/)

Comment: У меня в программе в некоторых командах выбираются воркеры по определенному условию (не только по минимальному количеству блокировок), а из BufferBlock, насколько я знаю, можно получить только первый свободный.

Comment: @DimaGvozdev в таком случае вам нужна более сложная реализация очереди, но общий смысл остается - очередь должна быть одна и снаружи воркера, а не внутри него.

Comment: @DimaGvozdev Если распишите логику выбора воркера подробнее - могу помочь с подбором алгоритма.

Comment: Добавил описание.

Answer (score 0):

Я бы попробовал для начала очевидное:

```
public class Worker
{
    AsyncLock _lock = new AsyncLock();
    object _countLock = new object();
    int _lockWaitCount = 0;

    public int GetLockWaitCount()
    {
        lock (_countLock)
            return _lockWaitCount;
    }

    public async Task ActionFirst()
    {
        lock (_countLock) _lockWaitCount++;
        using(await _lock.LockAsync())
        {
            lock (_countLock) _lockWaitCount--;
            // code
        }
    }

    public async Task ActionSecond()
    {
        lock (_countLock) _lockWaitCount++;
        using(await _lock.LockAsync())
        {
            lock (_countLock) _lockWaitCount--;
            // code
        }
    }
}
```

и выбирал бы `Worker`'а с наименьшим `GetLockWaitCount()`. Это всё можно обернуть в класс `AsyncLockWithCount`, чтобы не повторять код:

```
class AsyncLockWithCount
{
    AsyncLock _lock = new AsyncLock();
    object _countLock = new object();
    int _lockWaitCount = 0;

    public int GetLockWaitCount()
    {
        lock (_countLock)
            return _lockWaitCount;
    }

    async Task<IDisposable> LockAsync()
    {
        lock (_countLock) _lockWaitCount++;
        var result = await _lock.LockAsync();
        lock (_countLock) _lockWaitCount--;
        return result;
        // ну или try/finally, если вам больше нравится
    }
}
```

---

Для случая, когда нужно «отпускать» счётчик лишь по окончанию работы, можно воспользоваться такой модификацией:

```
class AsyncLockWithCount
{
    AsyncLock _lock = new AsyncLock();
    object _countLock = new object();
    int _lockWaitCount = 0;

    public int GetLockWaitCount()
    {
        lock (_countLock)
            return _lockWaitCount;
    }

    async Task<IDisposable> LockAsync()
    {
        lock (_countLock) _lockWaitCount++;
        var innerDisposable = await _lock.LockAsync();
        return new ActionDisposable(() =>
            {
                innerDisposable.Dispose();
                lock (_countLock) _lockWaitCount--;
            });
    }
}

class ActionDisposable : IDisposable
{
    Action _a;
    public ActionDisposable(Action a) { _a = a; }
    public void Dispose() => _a();
}
```

Вместо `ActionDisposable` можно использовать [`Disposable.Create` из Reactive Extensions](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.reactive.disposables.disposable.create(v=vs.103).aspx).

Comment: В данном случае счетчик будет уменьшаться сразу после разблокирования, а не после завершения дейстия.

Comment: @DimaGvozdev: Ну да, но вам же нужен счётчик _ожидающих_? Это он и есть.

Comment: Если надо уменьшить счётчик после окончания отработки, уменьшайте его не перед `// code`, а после.

Comment: Да, нужно после `// code` уменьшать счетчик, но тогда не получится использовать класс AsyncLockWithCount

Comment: @DimaGvozdev: Ну так и это легко переписать. Момент.

Comment: @DimaGvozdev: Обновил, смотрите.

Answer (score 0):

На основе этой статьи (http://sanjeev.dwivedi.net/?p=292) и исходного кода библиотеки Nito.AsyncEx, написал вот такой класс:

```
public class AsyncLockWithCount
{
    private readonly Task<Releaser> _cachedTask;
    private readonly Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>> m_waiters = new Queue<TaskCompletionSource<bool>>();
    private int m_currentCount = 1;
    private readonly object _mutex;
    public int Count {
        get
        {
            lock(_mutex)
            {
                return m_currentCount == 1 ? 0 : (m_waiters.Count + 1);
            }
        }
    }
    public AsyncLockWithCount()
    {
        _mutex = new object();
        _cachedTask = Task.FromResult(new Releaser(this));
    }
    public Task<Releaser> LockAsync()
    {
        lock (_mutex)
        {
            if (m_currentCount > 0)
            {
                --m_currentCount;

                return _cachedTask;
            }
            else
            {
                TaskCompletionSource<bool> waiter = new TaskCompletionSource<bool>();
                m_waiters.Enqueue(waiter);

                return waiter.Task.ContinueWith((_, state) => new Releaser((AsyncLockWithCount)state),
                    this, CancellationToken.None,
                    TaskContinuationOptions.ExecuteSynchronously, TaskScheduler.Default);
            }
        }
    }
    internal void Release()
    {
        TaskCompletionSource<bool> toRelease = null;

        lock (_mutex)
        {
            if (m_waiters.Count > 0)
                toRelease = m_waiters.Dequeue();
            else
                ++m_currentCount;
        }

        if (toRelease != null)
            toRelease.SetResult(true);
    }
    public struct Releaser : IDisposable
    {
        private readonly AsyncLockWithCount m_toRelease;

        internal Releaser(AsyncLockWithCount toRelease)
        {
            m_toRelease = toRelease;
        }
        public void Dispose()
        {
            if (m_toRelease != null)
                m_toRelease.Release();
        }
    }
}
```

Свойство Count возвращает количество текущих блокировок. Изначально доступно 1 место в очереди, значит еще никто не использовал блокировку, а если блокировка использована (m_currentCount != 1), то возвращается - размер очереди + 1. +1 потому что самая первая блокировка не попадает в очередь, а ее надо учитывать.